# nusoap library compatible with PHP 7.4

Tags: nusoap

I have used nusoap PHP library for soap request handling. It worked perfectly with PHP 5.4. I had to upgrade my PHP version to 7.4. Can anyone suggest or provide the suitable nusoap version match for PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

this lib https://github.com/f00b4r/nusoap
Supports PHP 5.4 to 8.1